# On the transmit weight vector in MIMO-MRC systems

Tags: signal-detection, optimization, mimo

Recently, I am reading paper [1]. In this paper, the author wrote:

> In MIMO-MRC systems in the absence of interferers, the signal vector at the received $n_R$ antennas is given by
>   $$\mathbf{r} = \sqrt{P_0} \mathbf{H}_0 \mathbf{w}_T s_0 + \mathbf{n}, \tag{1}$$
>   and the decision variable for detecting the transmitted symbol $s_0$ is obtained by combining with a weight vector $\mathbf{w}_R$. The combined signal at the receiver is given by
>   $$ z = \mathbf{w}^H_R \mathbf{r} = \sqrt{P_0} \mathbf{w}^H_R \mathbf{H}_0 \mathbf{w}_T s_0 + \mathbf{w}^H_R \mathbf{n}. \tag{2}$$
>   To maximize the signal component, the principle of maximum ratio transmission (MRT) can be used, then the transmit weight vector $\mathbf{w}_T$ can be chosen as $$ \mathbf{w}_T = \frac{\mathbf{H}_0^H \mathbf{w}_R}{\| \mathbf{H}_0^H \mathbf{w}_R \|}. \tag{3} $$

My question is: Why the transmit weight vector can be chosen as
$$ \mathbf{w}_T = \frac{\mathbf{H}_0^H \mathbf{w}_R}{\| \mathbf{H}_0^H \mathbf{w}_R \|}? \tag{4}$$
Thank you very much.

**Note**

- Vectors are expressed in boldface lower case letters, e.g., $\mathbf{a}$, and matrices are boldface capital letters, e.g., $\mathbf{A}$.
- $P_0$ is the average received power.
- $\mathbf{H}_0$ is the $n_R \times n_T$ channel matrix.
- $n_T$ is the number of transmit antennas.
- $\mathbf{w}_T$ is the beamforming vector at the transmitter with unit
  norm, i.e., $\| \mathbf{w}_T \|^2 = 1$.
- The additive thermal noise $\mathbf{n}$ is a complex Gaussian vector with mean vector $\mathbf{0}$ and covariance matrix $\sigma_n^2 \mathbf{I}$.
- We assume that the noise power per antenna is identical.
- The matrix Hermitian is denoted by $\mathbf{A}^H$.
- The Euclidean norm of vector $\mathbf{a}$ is denoted by $ \| \mathbf{a} \| $.

**Reference**

[1] K. S. Ahn, "Performance analysis of MIMO-MRC system in the presence of multiple interferers and noise over Rayleigh fading channels," in *IEEE Transactions on Wireless Communications*, vol. 8, no. 7, pp. 3727-3735, July 2009.
doi: 10.1109/TWC.2009.080940

Comment: Good question! So, what happens when you insert $\mathbf w_T$ into equation $(2)$? Hint: what does $\mathbf H_0 \mathbf H_0^H$ w.r.t symmetry? ($\mathbf H$ has symmetry properties)

Comment: Could you write down "*maximize* the signal component" in term of mathematical expression?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Let me think about it. I will reply to you later.

Comment: @AlexTP Let me think about it. I will reply to you later.

Comment: @MarcusMuller When I insert $\mathbf{w}_T$ into equation (2), $z=\sqrt{P_0} \cdot\frac{\mathbf{w}_R^H \mathbf{H}_0 \mathbf{H}_0^H \mathbf{w}_R}{\|\mathbf{H}_0^H \mathbf{w}_R\|}\cdot s_0+\mathbf{w}_R^H\mathbf{n}.$ From [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix] we know that $\mathbf{H}_0 \mathbf{H}_0^H$ is a Hermitian positive semi-definite matrix. Therefore, $\mathbf{w}_R^H \mathbf{H}_0 \mathbf{H}_0^H \mathbf{w}_R$ must be positive or zero (i.e. non-negative) for every nonzero column vector $\mathbf{w}_R$ of $n_R$ complex numbers [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix].

Comment: @AlexTP $\max \|\sqrt{P_0} \mathbf{w}^H_R \mathbf{H}_0 \mathbf{w}_T s_0\|^2.$

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu exactly! So, what's the value of $\|\mathbf H_0^H \mathbf w_R\|$, or: how does one compute that?

Comment: @MarcusMüller OK, let me think about your question. I will reply to you later. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller One can compute the value of $\| \mathbf{H}_0^H \mathbf{w}_R \|$ as follows: 1. Find $\mathbf{H}_0^H$. 2. Multiply $\mathbf{H}_0^H$ and $\mathbf{w}_R$ together. 3. Computer the norm of $\mathbf{a} := \mathbf{H}_0^H \mathbf{w}_R$ by summing up the squared absolute values of all elements in $\mathbf{a}$ and taking the squared root.

Comment: right :) @Wei-ChengLiu since we ² afterwards, we can just drop the squared root, and then we end with "summing up the squared absolute values", and that can be represented by a vector operation: $\|a\|^2 = a^H a$ . So, when considering $$\|\mathbf H_0^H \mathbf w_r\|^2=\mathbf w_r^H\mathbf H_0\mathbf H_0^H \mathbf w_r\text,$$ you'll recognize the term from the enumerator and denominator :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, I understand. So why the transmit weight vector can be chosen as (4)?

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu did you get the answer for this question? I think that's logic. .

Comment: @Zeyad_Zeyad Yes, I have gotten the answer for this question.